# Is it possible to use Azure Policy or anything else to validate the tasks of an Azure Pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'd like to use Azure Deployment Pipelines with approvers set in the pre-deployment condition. Then, only the approver can let a deployment go to production, for example. However, I can't be sure that all pipelines have the approval step configured. What if someone forgets to add it? Or if someone removes it by mistake?

It seems like Azure Policy would be a good fit but I don't know if we can write policy to cover build and deployment pipelines. I can think of many other examples too. Such as, all build numbers should be formatted a certain way.

How can I validate/audit Azure Pipelines?

Comment: You can set branch policies to ensure build validation of branches, and you can setup security around who is able to edit releases, but there is no way that I know of to force policies on releases if someone has permission to edit a release.

Comment: I dont think there is anything like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such kind of build-in policy to manage build and release pipelines.

The only way is using security permission to limit other users to modify them. Related Permission：

> ***Edit build pipeline***
>
> Can save any changes to a build pipeline, including configuration
>   variables, triggers, repositories, and retention policy.
>
> ***Edit release pipeline***
>
> Can save any changes to a release pipeline, including configuration
>   variables, triggers, artifacts, and retention policy as well as
>   configuration within a stage of the release pipeline. To make changes
>   to a specific stage in a release pipeline, the user also needs Edit
>   release stage permission.

More details please take a look at our official link：[Build and release permissions and security roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/policies/permissions?view=azure-devops)

Besides, you could also file up a feature request in our [Develop Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html) site. Choose "suggest a feature", our PM team will kindly review it.